# Python Matplotlib - shift image so certain position is assigned certain value in axis

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, image-processing

I have a question where I am not even sure what to search for to find an answer - so I am extremely grateful for every help (from direct solutions to this problems, links to other helpful threads, or even just some keyword or name of the issue I describe).

So I have quadratic images (png files) that show something (if that matters: it is astronomical data, showing a region which consists of certain objects that matter to my work). In those images I want to mark certain objects shown there, which I already successfully do using pandas data frames containing the positions of the objects that have to be marked.
But now I want to do something where I am lost:
So far, the images are having the pixels as x- and y-axis (e.g. 700 x 700 pixels, which means both axis run from 0 to 700). But I want to transform this now to another unit (in this case arcseconds and R.A. and Dec. on the axis) and with one specific object in the origin.
I do have the data of the objects positions in both the pixel position as in the image scale, as well as in the other unit I want to display (even as distance to the object that I want to put into the origin, both in x- and y-direction separately). So logically I think it should be possible to shift and re scale it properly - but I am totally lost in how to get my code to do this.

I can not be the first person trying to figure something like this out. Is there maybe a better name for this issue that I can search for? Or does anyone can point me to a solution?

I hope this question is okay, I am now in this forum and also not that experienced in programming yet. So please bear with me (and I am happy to get any hints how to improve).
Thank you very much in advance!

*Edit based on advice given to me (thank you for that!)*:
Here is what I get right now:  [current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYW4u.png)
Here is what I want to get (made with paint, so not very nice, but hopefully conveys the basic idea): [goal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2FLb.png)

Some parts of the code, that hopefully can help:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_with_all_the_data_needed, sep='\t', header=[0, 1], encoding_errors="replace")
df.columns = ... # the columns are named, afterwards other variables defined


number_of_datasets = len(df)
annotate_objects = ... # list of objects that should be marked


for i in range(number_of_datasets):
    j = i #+2
    img = plt.imread(df['filename'][j])
    print(img)

    width, height, value = img.shape
    

    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(img)

    
    for k in range(len(annotate_objects)):

        plt.annotate ... # annotations added here
                    
        
        
    plt.title(df['epoch'][j])
    # plt.axis('off')
    plt.savefig('Image__%.1f_with_objects_annotations.png' % df['epoch'][j])
    plt.show()
    break
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Please provide some code (and maybe image examples of what you have/what you want it to be) so others can better understand your question. If if is just about recentering the image, you might want to look at ``matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_position`` but I am not sure what exactly you want to convert to arcseconds.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the feedback!
Here is what I have so far: https://ibb.co/7G1Dbry
Here is what I want it to look like (made this with paint, so not ideal image, but it should show the basic idea): https://ibb.co/7G1Dbry

I am not sure if the code would actually be helpful, this is why I did not include it so far. There are a lot of other aspects included that are irrelevant for this question and probably confusing. Does it still make sense to upload the code?
Thank you!

Comment: Both of them are the same link - it would be great if you could edit your answer to include the images and the code snippets.

Comment: Oh ups, thanks for point that out! I edited the original question and included the right images and some code parts. I hope this helps? 
Thank you for your advice, I really appreciate it!!

Comment: @Keks. Centering the image around and object is fairly easy. One way I can think of is to pad image using numpy and use "fancy indexing" to select the correct portion of the padded image. Another option would be PIL's `Image.crop()`. Rescaling the image is more tricky. Since there is no direct conversion between pixels and physical units, you will need some sort of reference.

Comment: Hi and thank you for the answers!

By now I found a way to rescale the image on my own. Indeed I need a reference to convert between pixels and physical units, but I have that so it works well. I discovered the ` extent= ` function for that and it works more or less, although I still need to figure out how to avoid the image to be distorted afterwards.
But I still struggle with the centering around object part. Cropping is not what I need as I want the image to stay the same, just the axis should be shifted. So still looking forwards to any useful hints on that. Thanks again!